# Given the existence of Flesh to Ice/Salt, why use Flesh to Stone?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

My understanding is that these two spells are exactly the same as Flesh to Stone, but one spell level lower. If that is the case (and admittedly, I don't have Flesh to Salt handy), why ever learn/prepare/use Flesh to Stone instead of these?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Flesh to salt* has a distinct drawback relative to *flesh to stone*: it deals 1d6 damage per 2 levels, and then only if the target’s remaining hp is below half their total after that damage does it trigger the Fortitude save against being turned to a pillar of salt. In other words, *flesh to salt* has an extra failure mode, and is largely wasted on targets that aren’t already hurt (or have oddly low hp for the level). The fact that it “also” deals damage is kind of irrelevant, since the damage is poor.

(*Flesh to salt* is broken for an entirely different reason: D&D 3.5e defines the value of salt, and it is high. The massive amount of salt you can potentially generate with *flesh to salt* or *wall of salt* can break all notions of balancing the economy into itty bitty pieces. These spells are hardly unique in this—after all, rules as written, 10-ft. ladders can be split in twain and sold as a pair of 10-ft. poles at a substantial profit, so magic doesn’t even have to come into play here. The answer to these issues is always “D&D isn’t a market simulator and doesn’t have rules for supply and demand because that’s not the game it’s trying to be, and the group should either agree to play the game it actually is or else find a different system to run their game of Salt Tycoon.”)

*Flesh to ice*, on the other hand, is strictly superior to *flesh to stone*, since it is a level lower, and assuming you want to eliminate your target, ice is easier to eliminate after the fact than stone is. I suppose one could make the argument that if you are using *flesh to ____* in the first place, the entire point is to trap someone in that form for an extended period of time (to prevent resurrection), and thus ice is actually worse than stone, but that’s a stretch—definitely not a justification for discounting a whole spell level. *Frostburn* is kind of notorious for having a number of deeply problematic spells and magical mechanics (*ice assassin*, *shivering touch*, Snowcasting), so that is a bit par for the course in that book.